Active Byte Propagation in AES-256
I have questions about the active byte propagation in AES-256. Why does the third row, after the MixColumns operation, change from being fully active to only diagonally active? This is from Fig. 2 of the paper. Is this related to the MDS matrix?



Why does the third row, after the MixColumns operation, change from being fully active to only diagonally active?

Because it is a best-case (from the attacker's perspective) differential propagation; that is, one that minimizes the number of sboxes.
Yes, it has to do with the MDS matrix; that has the property that (except for trivial differentials) the total number of active inputs and active outputs is at least 5.
And, because the mix column step of AES consists of 4 parallel MDS matrices, this limit applies to each of them individually.
Because of this constraint, if all 4 inputs are active (that is, there is an active differential somewhere on each of the 4 input bytes), then there will be at least 1 active output differential.  This active output differential can be any of the 4 outputs, and could potentially have more than one (although this differential doesn't assume that).
Now, if the question is "why are the 4 active differentials in a diagonal line".  Well, that's to make things work out for the later steps of this differential - it is allowed by the constraints of the MDS matrix, and so we assume it is possible.
